# GET_ENTITY query for selecting 4 columns of a single table row

Tags: select, odata, abap

I am writing a `SELECT` query for oData service `EMPLOYEESET_GET_ENTITY` (code below) but I am getting warnings saying:

```
The database field or the result type of the aggregate function NACHN and the component "PERNR" of "ER_ENTITY" are not compatible.
```

SELECT query:

```
method EMPLOYEESET_GET_ENTITY.

    DATA: ls_keytab TYPE LINE OF /IWBEP/T_MGW_NAME_VALUE_PAIR,
          enteredPernr TYPE string.

    LOOP AT it_key_tab INTO ls_keytab.
      enteredPernr = ls_keytab-value.
    ENDLOOP.

    SELECT SINGLE pernr nachn vorna gbdat
      INTO er_entity
      FROM pa0002
      WHERE pernr = enteredPernr.

endmethod.
```

I am basically just selecting 4 columns of a single row from only 1 table named `pa0002`. `PERNR` is the key, so it should not really interfere with `NACHN`. I already checked types and all those properties have `Edm.String` and correspondig Max. length. The order of selected columns in my `SELECT` query corresponds with the order of those columns I specified when the entity type `Employee` was being created.

What exactly is the problem?

Comment: The structure is probably different. Use `INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF` to avoid this problem.

Comment: Or try to declare result structure inline: `SELECT SINGLE ... INTO @DATA(er_ent)`

Comment: @Suncatcher: My guess is, that your approach won't work, because the exporting variable `er_ent` has already been declared in the MPC classes which are auto-generated from the CDS DDL source.

Comment: If it is auto-generated, then it is about `er_entity` and my var is named `er_ent`, so there will be no conflict, probably

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF er_entity` as below.

```
method EMPLOYEESET_GET_ENTITY.

    DATA: ls_keytab TYPE LINE OF /IWBEP/T_MGW_NAME_VALUE_PAIR,
          enteredPernr TYPE string.

    LOOP AT it_key_tab INTO ls_keytab.
      enteredPernr = ls_keytab-value.
    ENDLOOP.

    SELECT SINGLE Pernr Nachn Vorna Gbdat
      INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF er_entity
      FROM pa0002
      WHERE pernr = enteredPernr.

endmethod.
```